# Where should we use \pstVerb?

Tags: pstricks

I have some constants as well as macros to be defined for PostScript.

```
\pstVerb
{   
  /a {3} def
  /b {2} def
}
```

There are three possible places:

- In the preamble (A).
- In `document` but outside `pspicture` (B).
- In `pspicture` (C).

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks]{standalone}
% A
\begin{document}
% B
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-4)(4,4)
% C
\psellipse(0,0)(!a b)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

For option A and B, I got unnecessary white spaces as follows.

[image]

But for option C,

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-4)(4,4)
\pstVerb
{   /a {3} def
/b {2} def
}%
\psellipse(0,0)(!a b)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

the white spaces no longer exit.

[image]

## Question

Where should we use `\pstVerb`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can it use where you want, but you have to pay attention that you do not
overwrite existing definitions. `/a` and `/b` are already defined in several ways
for internal functions.

Use always variables with at least two letters or use an own dictionary:

```
\documentclass[border=15pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\pstVerb{   
    /aA 3 def
    /bB 2 def
}
\pstVerb{
  /myDict 2 dict def % define a local dictionary with two variables
  myDict begin
    /a 3 def
    /b 2 def
  end
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \psellipse(0,0)(! myDict begin a b end )
    \psellipse(0,1)(! aA bB )
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

For C it works because `pspicture`  holds all local.

Comment: I was using PSTricks for several years to create many graphics. However, the possibility of a local dictionary is complete new to me. This is very useful to avoid conflicts with internal commands already defined. Thanks!